# Default folder structure in ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, references

I anticipate having to develop a front-end for an ArcGIS server, and until it's ready I've just been poking around the web interface of an existing instance to get a general understanding of where things are.

For example, I can find the main list of available services [here](http://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/arcgis/rest/), and the generic API documentation [here](http://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/arcgis/sdk/rest/).

What other standard locations exist in a default ArcGIS setup, if no customization is done (or, equivalently, where I can find such information)?

---

I looked into the links posted by @Mapperz in the comments, and while they were informative about migrating to 10.2, they didn't talk much about conventions or defaults for the ArcGIS web interface. The second link mentioned the `arcgis/rest/services` convention, but that was one of the ones I had already discovered.

Comment: What Version of ArcGIS Server? (things are changing for 10.2)

Comment: I believe it will be 10.2.1

Comment: Check http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0154000002nz000000 & http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Migration_checklist/0154000005n9000000/

Comment: That site mentions that the default site name is `arcgis`, but beyond that doesn't seem to talk much about the layout of a standard installation, unless I'm missing something :-/

Comment: There are conventions used in documentation and training, but every site is free to implement whatever they want, as it suits their situation. I doubt there is a "typical setup," at least from the standpoint of making assumptions of where to find resources.

Comment: @Vince That's a good point. Do you think my question would be more accurate if I worded it to ask not about "typical" setups but rather about the "default" configuration? I have found that the `arcgis/rest` and `arcgis/sdk/rest` convention seems to appear frequently in online installations, which leads me to believe that many users simply keep the default configuration. I'm still interested in finding the proper documentation on those defaults.

Comment: There isn't much in a "default" configuration, so you're still on shaky ground there.  Folder structure follows scope and scale of the project.  The ends of the URLs are common, but getting there may be a bumpy ride

Comment: @Vince I guess I'm less concerned with exactness and more with "where do these defaults come from". Is there somewhere where the `/arcgis/sdk/rest` convention is documented as the default location for the API documentation?

Comment: It seems like your question may be changing as a result of comments by @Vince but you have not yet revised it.  Would you be able to use the [edit] button to let us know what your current single question is, please?